# obscuring / securing filepicker / filestack urls

Tags: filepicker.io

I use filepicker to serve resized / cropped / watermarked images on a website. I use the regular URL based API to do this: e.g. a url might look like `https://.../convert?h=400&amp;w=600&amp;fit=crop&amp;quality=80&amp;format=jpg&amp;cache=true`

This obviously allows a lot of flexibility for sizing images on the fly and so on. However, it also means that anyone can get the original un-cropped, un-watermarked image by removing the parameters at the end of the URL.

Is there any way around this short of creating a proxy server that could un-encode an encoded string?

For the latest version, it seems you need to add in your API key to the URL as well - what would stop someone else from using my API key? Are these URLs really meant to be used on a production website in the `<img>` tags? or for creating a resized image to download, store and ultimately serve up to the end user?

Answer (score 1):

We have updated our processing engine so that it is no longer necessary to pass an API key if you are transforming an image based on its Filestack Handle:

https://process.filestackapi.com/watermark=file:ZoVdwbe6Qcu9uIxIZSuU/h2T4Jl9RBSSXOGtl0gv8

However, a user could still get the image without the watermark. So, we also have a store method built into the processing engine:

Posting the image with our store task attached:

```
curl -X POST -g "https://process.filestackapi.com/store/watermark=file:ZoVdwbe6Qcu9uIxIZSuU/h2T4Jl9RBSSXOGtl0gv8"
```

Will return the following:

```
{"filename":"photo-1435771112039-1e5b2bcad966.jpg","height":750,"size":67588,"type":"image/jpeg","url":"https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/62aWdbPvQzWNrl90C7q9","width":1000}
```

Which is a saved version of the watermarked image, so the watermark cannot be removed:

https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/62aWdbPvQzWNrl90C7q9

Answer (score 0):

We recommend using the newer method but you should also set up security so that people can't hotlinking to your content.

https://www.filepicker.com/docs/security/

I would also recommend move over to Filestack as it we have rebuilt all the infrastructure.